# How to make an if statement with JSONT

Tags: conditional-statements, squarespace, jsontemplate

How can I check a property for a specific value??

IE: The JSONT version of

```
if(someProperty == someValue){
      //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control-of-flow syntax for if is:

```
{.if pagination}
// Do some stuff
{.end}
```

But if you're looking to do if/equals then:

```
{.equal? @index 1}
// Do some stuff
{.end}
```

That said, it appears that JSONT is a forked language without an active community working on any particular implementation so the syntax will vary.  In this case, I'm referring to Squarespace's implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally template should be free from such logic,Way to solve this problem is to break down the templates where one template to have the common stuff and many smaller ones which you need to apply only under certain condition, then have the condition in javascript code.

Answer (score -1):

Try {.equal? someProperty someValue}

Comment: What possible results do you foresee for that experiment? For each of them, what would be the actual solution you recommend based on them? Also, this seems pretty similar to what is proposed and much better explained (i.e. at least a little) in the existing and upvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095083/7733418 Please [edit] to make more obvious what additional insight you contribute.